# In MS Excel, I need to delete every alternate row AUTOMATICALLY rather than MANUALLy, how can it be done WITH EXCEL?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

> #### Already asked on Super User:
>
> [In MS Excel, I need to delete every alternate row AUTOMATICALLY rather than MANUALLY.](https://superuser.com/questions/216368/)

basically i'm working on an excel spreadsheet in which I have to delete every alternate row because it is messing up with my results.

Its a set of 4000 randomly generated set of data.

Hence, deleting 2000 wud take about 30 mins, can it be done in 30 seconds using EXCEL alone and avoiding Programming?

Is there any trick to do that in MS Excel?

Comment: If you wish to avoid programming, you should ask this on superuser.com, and not on stackoverflow.com. Also: Why is this tagged ms-access? =)

Comment: Excel, C#, what's the difference ;-). Removed the tags.

Answer (score 14):

In a new column (say "X") use

```
=MOD(ROW(L2),2)
```

and expand the column over the whole set. That should give you an alternating sequence of 0 and 1. Now auto-filter and select only the 0s (or the 1s), then hit delete.

Edit: You may have to look up your local version of the functions, if you are not using english excel. For example in Germany it would be REST(ZEILE(X1),2)). MOD is the modulo function, LINE should give you the current line number.

Answer (score 0):

Your question even has it's own Knowledgebase article: [How to delete every other row on an Excel worksheet](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213610) which **does** involve some programming - you won't get around that. But at least it is copy 'n paste programming ;-)

```
Sub Delete_Every_Other_Row()

   ' Dimension variables.
   Y = False              ' Change this to True if you want to
                          ' delete rows 1, 3, 5, and so on.
   I = 1
   Set xRng = Selection

   ' Loop once for every row in the selection.
   For xCounter = 1 To xRng.Rows.Count

       ' If Y is True, then...
       If Y = True Then

           ' ...delete an entire row of cells.
           xRng.Cells(I).EntireRow.Delete

       ' Otherwise...
       Else

           ' ...increment I by one so we can cycle through range.
           I = I + 1

       End If

       ' If Y is True, make it False; if Y is False, make it True.
       Y = Not Y

   Next xCounter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

@user524100: I think you'll have to use a macro for that, fortunately one already exists that you can get from here: http://www.bridgetonova.com/2009/07/how-to-delete-every-other-row-in-excel.html

Comment: Step 1: Add a new column
Step 2: write if condition like:  if(B1<>"","1","nil")
Step 3: apply this formula for all rows.
Step 4: sort by newly created column.
Step 5: you will get only rows having data; copy and use it.